# Изменить текущую версию темы WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне бы хотелось обновить версию файла `style.css` на своём сайте WordPress.

Текущая версия имеет такой вид:

```
https://site/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/style.css?ver=5.5.5
```

У меня есть функция регистрации стилей в `functions.php`:

```
function twentytwenty_register_styles() {

$theme_version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwenty-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), $theme_version );

wp_style_add_data( 'twentytwenty-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

// Add output of Customizer settings as inline style.
wp_add_inline_style( 'twentytwenty-style', twentytwenty_get_customizer_css( 'front-end' ) );

// Add print CSS.
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwenty-print-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/print.css', null, $theme_version, 'print' ); }
```

Мне нужно понять, где я могу ***указать** версию используя переменную* `$theme_version`.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_theme` получает объект WP_Theme, который содержит информацию о текущей теме. Для того чтобы изменить версию файлов стилей и скриптов используя текущий функционал вам нужно изменить параметр `version` в файле style.css который лежит в корне темы. Но стоит учитывать момент что если тема платная либо из репозитория то вы не получите обновление пока ваша версия не будет меньше основной версии. Если вы используете дочернюю тему то в ней может не быть параметра `version` соответственно вы можете его добавить сами

Answer (score 0):

Решение моего вопроса оказалось довольно простым. 
Нужно в `style.css` добавить информацию о теме.

```
Version: 5.5.6
```